# newbie here can i recover complete old website?

Tags: web, archive, recovery

The way back machine does not have the midi or gifs that were originally on the pages. Is it possible to find them? I am trying to restore my mother's site she developed before she passed away

Comment: You could try looking around for other webpage archives like http://archive.is or maybe Google cached pages, http://www.cachedpages.com. I think you might have more luck looking locally on any computers or hard drives you have.

Comment: thanks for the response, I did try Google pages, reocities.com and even oocities.org but nothing more there. Archive.is however sounds like it is worth looking at. I will try it, thanks again

Comment: If you know the hosting provider it may be worth contacting them and inquiring as to if they maintained an old archive- long shot - but worth a try.

Comment: Funny you should mention that. I just found a site called Webrings and they actually have my mother's site listed but upon my query I was blocked from the site, now only approved members can reach them. I have most of what I was looking for but the midi and gifs she had would have been nice. I just do not know how to pull them from the pages to restore. Some worked, some didn't. Any idea why not all came through?

Answer (score 0):

If this website was one Geocities, perhaps you can try searching geocities.ws as well, like so: https://www.google.com/#q=site:geocities.ws+keyword (replace keyword with the name of the website). If you give us the old URL, perhaps we can find more.

Comment: I did try that but it just goes to error page. The archive they mirrored on was Oocities. I was able to get most from there, the Wayback Machine and Reocities. None were able to restore an entire page. Always something missing on each page.